# How do I Reduce the size of eclipse view tabs in Ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

The size of eclipse tabs such as Console, Progress, Markers etc are very big in Ubuntu compared to Windows how do I reduce the size of those.

Comment: Attach screen shots or share it here http://imgur.com

Answer (score 0):

I used Unity Tweak Tool to reduce the font size of Ubuntu and it solved my problem.